# dynamic ui:include with el-expression?

Tags: jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0.

Is there a way to make this code work?

```
<ui:repeat value="#{theBean.tabList}" var="tab">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{theBean.chose == tab.tabHash}">
        <h:outputText value="TESTING #{tab.tabName} (#{tab.tabFile})" />
        <ui:include src="#{tab.tabFile}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

Specifically, the line `<ui:include src="#{tab.tabFile}" />`.
Currently I get a blank page (Meaning, I guess, that `#{tab.tabFile}` evaluated to null\empty.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<ui:include>` runs during view build time (to generate the JSF component tree) while the `<ui:repeat>` runs during view render time (to generate the HTML output), which is after the view build time. Use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<ui:repeat>`, it runs during view build time as well.

#### See also:

- [`c:forEach` vs `ui:repeat` in Facelets](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat)

Comment: since c:forEach works during the view build time how is the value for iterable referenced by EL expression available as that should be available atleast after Apply Request Values Phase ?!

Comment: @user01: I'm not sure if I understand your confusion. The restore view phase (the view build time) runs just before apply request values phase.