# Why does ui:Include behavior vary with different bean scopes?

Tags: jsf-2, cdi

I have been tinkering around with ui:include lately and have found it to be fairly quirky in many of its behaviors.  After a some testing, it seems to me like these quirks have to do with issues go back to how ui:include fits into the jsf lifecycle.  I am trying to get a better grasp on the framework, and was wondering if anyone could help me understand what is going on.

Take the following example:

index.xhtml

```
<h:panelGrid id="testInclude">
    <ui:include src="#{bean.pageTarget}.xhtml" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

bean (ManagedBean, SessionScoped)

```
public String getPageTarget() { return "pageA"; }
@PostConstruct
public void init() { System.out.println("new bean created"); }
```

pageA.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <h:outputText value="You are on page: #{bean.pageTarget}" />
</ui:composition>
```

When the page is first rendered, two bean instances are created.  This is directly related to there being a reference to bean in pageA.  Based on one of BalusC's previous answers, this probably has to do with when ui:include is processed: [dynamic ui:include with el-expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927723/dynamic-uiinclude-with-el-expression)

The curious thing is that changing bean to use CDI's conversation scope actually gets rid of this problem.  Does anyone know why this works?

Comment: Try the following (I haven't tested it, but if it works, I'll make it an answer):
`<ui:include src="${bean.pageTarget}.xhtml"/>`
Expressions starting with `$` are evaluated by the Facelets engine, as is `<ui:include/>`, whereas expressions starting with `#` are processed in the JSF lifecycle. I can offer no clues as to why `@ConversationScoped` beans differ.

Comment: Interesting!  It did solve one issue I didn't mention (form elements dropping the hidden field data they use to identify themselves to the session when a ui:include is re-rendered via ajax).