# How can I retrieve an object on @WindowScoped?

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, codi

In this post [Dynamic ui:include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786793/dynamic-uiinclude) I asked how I could store an object in some state that could permit me to load a new windows, or tab, of the same browser and it was not stored also in the new windows. Adrian Mitev told me to use `@WindowScoped`, an option of MyFaces extension called CODI and i tried to implement it.

Now I should say that I'm blind and when I tried to open Apache Wiki my browser crashes on many pages so I can't read the guides.

However I add the source code on my project and the compiler didn't give any errors.
The problem is that now thepage when I try to retrive the bean that I stored by `@WindowScoped` doesn't work properly!

I use this code in my bean:

```
@ManagedBean (name="logicBean" )
@WindowScoped
```

In `include.xhtml` I retrieve the parameter with this code:

```
<ui:include src="#{logicBean.pageIncluded}"/>
```

And in my other beans I retrieve the `LogicBean` with this code (and I'm sure that the problem is on this code)

```
LogicBean l = (LogicBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("logicBean");
```

How can I retrive the "correct" LogicBean object?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to get the `LoginBean` from the session map. This works only for session scoped beans with the standard JSF `@SessionScoped` annotation.

The canonical way to access other beans is using `@ManagedProperty` on the retrieving bean.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OtherBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{logicBean}")
    private LogicBean logicBean;

    // Getter+Setter.
}
```

If you really need to access it inside the method block by evaluating the EL programmatically, you should be using [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) instead:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
LogicBean logicBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{logicBean}", LogicBean.class);
// ...
```

Comment: @ BalusC : Thank you very much! I knew that the code retrivied the object on the session but I didn't know how I could change it! Thanks again!