# Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, web-inf

After these questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589315/jsf2-dynamic-template
- [Dynamic ui:include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786793/dynamic-uiinclude)
- [How can I retrieve an object on @WindowScoped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911985/how-can-i-retrieve-an-object-on-windowscoped)
- [How can I check if an object stored with @WindowScoped is stored correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939037/how-can-i-check-if-an-object-stored-with-windowscoped-is-stored-correctly)
- [ICE Faces and error in creation of a bean in WindowScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001426/ice-faces-and-error-in-creation-of-a-bean-in-windowscoped)

that I wrote all to resolve a "stupid" issue for the JSF2 framework, the fact that I can't link directly to a page stored in a `/WEB-INF` subfolder. After that I did some research on Google and Stackoverflow I would know a thing: How do I structure a JSF2 web project?

In particular, where exactly do I put the XHTML pages?

Comment: This is an outstanding question which touches on many aspects of facelets.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Files in `/WEB-INF` folder are indeed not publicly accessible by enduser. So you cannot have something like `http://localhost:8080/contextname/WEB-INF/some.xhtml`. That would be a potential security hole as the enduser would be able to view among others `/WEB-INF/web.xml` and so on.

You can however use the `/WEB-INF` folder to put master template files, include files and tag files in. For example, the following template client `page.xhtml` which is placed outside `/WEB-INF` and is accessible by `http://localhost:8080/contextname/page.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
    <ui:define name="content">
        ...
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/include.xhtml" />
        ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The advantage of placing master templates and include files in `/WEB-INF` is that the enduser won't be able to open them directly by entering/guessing its URL in the browser addres bar. The normal pages and template clients which are intented to be accessed directly must not be placed in `/WEB-INF` folder.

By the way, the composite component files are in turn also not supposed to be publicly accessible, however they are by specification required to be placed in `/resources` folder which is by default publicly accesible. If you make sure that you access all resources using the [therefor provided components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727) so that they are never accessed by `/resources` in URL (but instead by `/javax.faces.resource`), then you can add the following constraint to `web.xml` to block all public access to the `/resources` folder:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict direct access to the /resources folder.</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>The /resources folder.</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```