# JSF with eclipse, maven & glassfish - Error: com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, glassfish, mojarra

I am trying to set up a simple JSF project w/ eclipse & maven. But I am stuck D:
Whenever I try to run my stuff, I get this error:

```
com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:232)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.resolveURL(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:209)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:230)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I understand it's my fault ... by I can't find it.
I just have a web.xml, (empty) faces-config.xml and an hello.xhtml which I want to display. All files are in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.
Please help :)

Here are the files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Hello</display-name>
<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<!-- JSF mapping -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<!-- Map these files with JSF -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
</faces-config>
```

The hello.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - hello.xhtml</h3>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{helloBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" action="welcome"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

asd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put the hello.xhtml in WEB-INF. Only config files have to go there. Put hello.xhtml into the dir where WEB-INF lies.

Comment: Stupid me! I thought I'd tried this, but apparently I didn't. Totally did the trick of course - thanks!

Comment: ... and template files which shouldn't be opened in public. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not