# Error: /login.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: jsf, url-pattern

I'm using JBoss 7.1 with JSF 2.1/Prime Faces and keep running into the error listed in the title. I've tried many of the suggestions made here and all end up with the same error.

File structure is:

```
WEB-INF
   faces
      login.xhtml
```

I have the following in web.xml:

```
<display-name>clientAccountManager</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I am accessing the file currently using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientAccountManager/faces/login.xhtml
```

I have also changed the URL pattern to *.xhtml and used:

```
http://localhost:8080/clientAccountManager/login.xhtml
```

with the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes.

1. `/WEB-INF` folder is for configuration files, include files, template files, tag files, etc, which are supposed to be hidden from direct access, not for publicly accessible files. Put publicly accessible files outside `/WEB-INF` folder.
2. `/faces` folder should not be used at all. A virtual `/faces/*` URL pattern on `FacesServlet` doesn't imply that you should have a physical folder like that. Remove it.

So, all with all, just

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- faces-config.xml
 |    `-- web.xml
 `-- login.xhtml
```

and

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and

```
http://localhost:8080/clientAccountManager/login.xhtml
```

should do.

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)

Comment: And this answer is better than http://stackoverflow.com/a/9033567/196561 because now you say where we should  to put the files to get the project working. Thank you again.