# Facelet template renders two HTML tags

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I am creating my first facelets/JSF application. In my first page I added a facelet template:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 
<f:view>
  <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </h:head>
  <body>
    <ui:insert name='top'>
      <ui:include src="/templates/template_a.xhtml"></ui:include>
</ui:insert>
  </body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

This is my template page:

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </h:head>
  <body>
    <ui:composition template="/inwert_a.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="top">
      <h2>naglowek</h2>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</body> 
</html>
```

But when I look at page source in my web browser I see this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>Insert title here</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>naglowek</h2>
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does JSF create a body and other HTML tags twice when I am using `<ui:composition>`?

---

After update my code looks that-main page:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"> 

 <h:head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
  <title>Insert title here</title> 
 </h:head> 
 <h:body>   
    <f:subview id="a">
        <ui:insert name="top">
           <ui:include src="aaa.xhtml" ></ui:include> 
        </ui:insert>
     </f:subview>
 </h:body> 
 </html>
```

template content:

```html
<ui:composition 
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 template="/mainpage.xhtml"
> 
  <ui:define name="top">
       <h2> aaaaaaaaa </h2>
  </ui:define>  

 </ui:composition>
```

this is source view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  
 /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title>Insert title here</title></head>
 <body>

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>     
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
 /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
 <body>
    <h2>aaaaaaaaa</h2>
 </body> 
</html>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're basically using templating the wrong way. You're basically using them "the other way round" from how it's supposed to be done. The page which you called "my template page" should be opened by its URL in the browser, not the page which you called "a facelet template". Best to prevent this mistake in the future is to store pages which you specify in `<ui:composition template>` (and `<ui:include src>`) inside `/WEB-INF` folder, so that they can never be opened directly by accident (or by hackers).

Here's a kickoff example which should work for your case:

`/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="top">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/top.xhtml">
        </ui:insert>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`/WEB-INF/templates/top.xhtml`:

```html
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <p>Some default content for top</p>
</ui:composition>
```

`/page.xhtml`

```html
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="title">
        New page title here
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="top">
        <h2>naglowek</h2>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Now, you should in your browser navigate to `/page.xhtml` (and thus not the template file).

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)
- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)

Comment: @BalucC I moved my template file to /WEB-INF but my browser source view is still the same.

Comment: I am using jsf.jar from Mojarra Project in Eclipse Juno. Maybe here is problem? Before I created this question , I had been serching in google very long but noone have similar problem to my. I think that my code is to simply to cause this error.

Comment: The problem is caused by something else which you added to the code yourself. You should start off with **exactly** the files I presented in my answer. Save and run it and then build further on it.

Comment: I wrote my comment too soon  - Your example not work :( I created new project.In WEB-INF\templates I put template.xhtml and top.xhtml, in WebContent I put page.xhtml. When I runing page.xhtml I see nothing from top or template content.

Comment: Is the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` mapped on an URL pattern of `*.xhtml`? If it's not then you would not see any generated HTML code, but only the raw JSF source code (rightclick page in browser and *View Source* to see what the browser actually retrieved). For a concrete example of the proper mapping, see the Hello World of [our JSF wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: @BalusC I want to thank You very, very much! Your answer and suggestions help me understand how should I useing facelets. One more time thanks :)