# how to include multiple xhtml pages, which are extending same template into a summary xhtml page,

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

How can we include multiple xhtml pages into a summary page.
Here all the xhtml pages including same template.

### commonTemplate.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<title> SNS </title>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sns.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<h:body>

    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="commonHeader">
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="commonBodyContent">
            Common Body Content.
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ui:insert name="commonFooter">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

### updatePersonalDetails.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        .........;
        ..........;
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

### updatedAddress.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        .........;
        ..........;
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

### selectPreferences.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        .........;
        ..........;
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

### summary.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:include src="updatePersonalDetails.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="updatedAddress.xhtml" />
    <ui:include src="selectPreferences.xhtml" />

</ui:composition>
```

Whatever the data i have in all xhtml pages, supposed to display exactly same in summary page. But including this causes multiple `<html>` documents to render on page.

How can we solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the body content into another template which you include by `<ui:include>` in the template clients as well.

E.g. `updatePersonalDetails.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        <ui:include src="updatePersonalDetails-content.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

*(repeat for the others as well)*

so that you can just do this in `summary.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                template="commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="commonBodyContent">
        <ui:include src="updatePersonalDetails-content.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="updatedAddress-content.xhtml" />
        <ui:include src="selectPreferences-content.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, consider placing templates and includes in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent them from being accessed directly. See also [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not/9033567#9033567)

Comment: How would one go about if `updatedAddress.xhtml`, `selectPreferences.xhtml` etc had more `ui:define`:s, in addition to `commonBodyContent`? Say, for example, a `secTitle` field. Is there a way to define it in `updatedAddress-content.xhtml` etc and use it in both `updatedAddress.xhtml` and `summary.xhtml`?

Comment: I think this is the same thing as is being asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156817/how-to-include-common-content-into-multiple-level-template-page).