# How to include common content into multiple level template page

Tags: jsf, facelets

I am trying include a common page into a template but all I get is a blank page without error.

common.xhtml actually has the content that indicate in the template.xhtml. It seems the template.xhtml doesn't recognize the two level include.

template.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
 xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
 xmlns:ub="http://jboss.com/products/seam/ub-taglib"
 xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich">

<head>
  <ui:insert name="css" />  
  <ui:insert name="header" />
</head>

<body>
 <ui:insert name="body" />  
</body>
</html>
```

custom.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    template="template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/custom.css/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:include src="common.xhtml" />

</ui:composition>
```

common.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich"
    xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    template="template.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="header">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <table><tr><td>Table</td></tr></table>
    </ui:define>    
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed won't work. The `<ui:define>` is supposed to be used in a template client (i.e. a page with `<ui:composition template="...">`), not in an include file (i.e. a page with `<ui:composition>` without `template`). You can however just "extend" from existing master templates.

Remove from `custom.xhtml`:

```
<ui:include src="common.xhtml" />
```

Change in `common.xhtml`

```
template="custom.xhtml"
```

And open `common.xhtml` instead of `custom.xhtml` in browser.

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, to prevent the enduser form being able to open `custom.xhtml` or `template.xhtml` directly in browser, it's recommended to move them into the `/WEB-INF` folder. Further, are you aware of the `<h:head>` and `<h:outputStylesheet>` components? I suggest to make use of them. Also, having a `<h1>` to ultimately end up in `<head>` makes no sense. Perhaps you meant the `<ui:insert name="header">` to be inside `<body>`? Further, you could easily put that `<h1>` in the template so that you don't need to repeat them in every template client.

`/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml`

```
<html ...>
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="header" />
        <ui:insert name="body" />
    </body>
</html>
```

`/WEB-INF/templates/custom.xhtml` (CSS file is placed in `/resources` folder)

```
<ui:composition ... template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="header">
        <h1><ui:insert name="custom-header" /></h1>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:outputStylesheet name="custom.css" target="head" />
        <ui:insert name="custom-body" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

`/page.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition ... template="/WEB-INF/templates/custom.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="custom-header">
        header
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="custom-body">
         <table><tr><td>Table</td></tr></table>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727)

Comment: thanks. I was thinking of extending the template before but my situation is not that simple. I have two templates for different modules and the common.xhtml is shared among this two modules.