# absolute path in jsf not working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to jsf.

I have basically 4 jsf files.

1) menu.xhtml

```html
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"    
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <h:head>

<h:body>

  <p:layout fullPage="true">
   <p:layoutUnit position="north" style="min-width: 300px;" gutter="0">
    <ui:insert name="header">
     <ui:include src="../../layout/header.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
   </p:layoutUnit>

   <p:layoutUnit position="center" style="border:none;" gutter="0">
    <p:panel id="content" style="background : transparent; border : 0;">
     <ui:include src="content.xhtml" />
    </p:panel>
   </p:layoutUnit>

   <p:layoutUnit position="west" collapsible="true" gutter="6"  >
   <h:panelGroup id="menu" layout="block">
   <h:form>
    <ul>
     <li><p:commandLink value="goto-include1" action="#{bean.doAction1}" update=":mainContent" ajax="true" /></li>
     <li><p:commandLink value="goto-include2" action="#{bean.doAction2}" update=":mainContent" ajax="true" /></li>
    </ul>
   </h:form>
  </h:panelGroup>
   </p:layoutUnit>

   <p:layoutUnit position="south" style="min-width: 300px;" gutter="0">
    <div id="footer" class="ui-widget ui-widget-header">
     <ui:include src="../../layout/footer.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </div>
   </p:layoutUnit>

  </p:layout>`enter code here`


 </h:body>
</f:view>
</h:html>
```

Include1.jsp

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:outputText value="Include1"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Include2.jsp

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:outputText value="Include1"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Include3.jsp

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:outputText value="Include1"/>
</ui:composition>
```

Content.jsp

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:panelGroup id="mainContent" layout="block">
        <ui:include src="#{bean.page}.xhtml" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</ui:composition>
```

My bean class is as

```
package com.assia.dslo.expresse.gui.component.pe;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private String page = "include3";
    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public void setPage(String page) {
        this.page = page;
    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -802772877129109794L;

    public void doAction1() {
        this.page = "expresse/pe/include1.xhtml";
    }

    public void doAction2() {
        this.page = "include2";
    }
}
```

The intended behavior is that when I click on the Include1 link , it displays the include1.jsf in the center frame and similarly for the Include2 link.

However, the absolute path for Include1 does not work. If I replace the absolute path by a relative path,then it works fine. Can somebody help me understand why this happens ? Is this an expected behavior or there is something wrong that I am doing .

Thanks

Comment: Absolute path works fine. Do your absolute path start with a slash (eg `/expresse/pe/include1.xhtml`) ? Absolute path start from the `webapp` dir, for a file stores in `src/main/webapp/a/b/c.xhtml` (I assume you use Maven), the absolute path will be `/a/b/c.xhtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absolute path starts with a slash `/` which will take your to the root. Your path does not start with a slash `/` and is therefore not an absolute path at all.

Fix it accordingly. Replace

```
this.page = "expresse/pe/include1.xhtml";
```

by

```
this.page = "/expresse/pe/include1.xhtml";
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, it's recommend to put files which are not supposed to be directly publicly accessible inside the `/WEB-INF` folder. Otherwise the enduser would get a partial/broken page when entering/guessing its path in the browser's address bar.

```
this.page = "/WEB-INF/expresse/pe/include1.xhtml";
```

Do the same for all your other include and template files. Don't forget to replace their relative paths by absolute paths starting with `/WEB-INF`.

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not/9033567#9033567)

Comment: Yes, you are right. This works. This is an extension of your solution to a previous problem in stackoverflow. Thanks for the help