# Javascript method not defined in Facelets

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

FireFox says my method, doSend, is not defined, but it is.
And Chrome says nothing about the websockets...

Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var image;
    var output;
    function init() {
        console.log('CONNECTED to websockets!');
        output = document.getElementById('output');
        testWebSocket();
    }

    //connects websocket to KwetterWebsocketBean
    function testWebSocket() {
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
            onOpen(evt);
        };
        websocket.onclose = function(evt) {
            onClose(evt);
        };
        websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
            onMessage(evt);
        };
        websocket.onerror = function(evt) {
            onError(evt);
        };
    }

    //define event handlers
    function onOpen(evt) {
    }            
    function onWindowClose(evt){
        websocket.close();
    }
    function onClose(evt) {
    }
    function onMessage(evt) {
        //convert json to javascript object
        var message = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        writeToScreen('<span style="color: green;">New tweet by ' + message.username + ': ' + message.text + '</span>');
        console.log(message.text + ' : ' + message.username);
        //write message.text to screen
    }

    function onError(event) {
    }

    function doSend(message) {
        console.log(message);
        websocket.send(message);
    }

    //appends text to #output
    function writeToScreen(text) {
        var pre = document.createElement('p');
        pre.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        pre.innerHTML = text;
        output.appendChild(pre);
    }

    //invoke init() on load
    window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

    //enter key clicks #sendButton
    function keyPressed(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            document.getElementById('sendButton').click();
            document.getElementById('textforws').value='';
        }
    }
</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./aTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="S1">
            <h1>What's happening?</h1>
            <h:form id="formNewestTweet">
                <p:inputText maxlength="140" value="aMessage"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Post Tweet" id="sendButton"                                     
                                 onclick='doSend("aMessage");'/>
            </h:form>
            <div id="output"/>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: In future questions, please don't overgeneralize Facelets as XHTML by using `[xhtml]` tag instead of `[facelets]`. Naive HTML/JS developers who overgeneralize XHTML as overhyped HTML don't know *real* XHTML as such. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3869174/157882

Comment: Added the script between <head> and </head>. It still does NOT work.

Comment: Try **reading** my answer. I said nowhere to put `<head>` and `</head>` around the script. Or if you were referring to someone else's answer, please comment to them instead of to me.

Comment: @BalusC The comment was addressed to the other answer, I'm trying yours now.

Comment: In the future, post such a comment in other's answer directly, instead of responding to my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Facelets, Any content outside `<ui:composition>` of a template client is **ignored**. Basically, you need to put the content inside `<ui:define>` of `<ui:composition>`.

There are in your particular case several ways to fix this wrong code:

1. Put it straight in `<ui:define>`.

   ```html
   <ui:composition template="./aTemplate.xhtml">
       <ui:define name="S1">
           <script type="text/javascript">
               ...
           </script>
           ...
       </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
   ```
2. The same way, but then using `<h:outputScript target="head">` instead of `<script>`. It'll automatically end up in HTML head (provided that you've a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in your master template `aTemplate.xhtml`):

   ```html
   <ui:composition template="./aTemplate.xhtml">
       <ui:define name="S1">
           <h:outputScript target="head">
               ...
           </h:outputScript>
           ...
       </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
   ```
3. Add a new `<ui:insert name="head">` to the bottom of `<h:head>` of your master template `aTemplate.xhtml` and declare in there instead:

   ```html
   <ui:composition template="./aTemplate.xhtml">
       <ui:define name="head">
           <script type="text/javascript">
               ...
           </script>
       </ui:define>

       <ui:define name="S1">
           ...
       </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>
   ```

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I recommend to put master template files in `/WEB-INF` folder and use it like so

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/aTemplate.xhtml">
```

otherwise endusers are able to open it individually and see raw (unparsed) source code.

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare methods between

```
  <head></head>
```

tag

Because all the script contained in head tag was rendered before the body tag

And the events inside body.