# h:outputStylesheet generates RES_NOT_FOUND URL for resources in /WEB-INF/resources

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources

I am trying to include my stylesheets within the `<h:head>` tag utilising the following JSF tag: `<h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" />`, however when I load my page I get RES_NOT_FOUND for this specific CSS resource when looking through dev tools in the web browser.

I am trying to call the stylesheet within one of my template files I have created, "default.xhtml". Please refer to the image attached below to see my project directory structure, and where the red arrow indicates where the  tag is being utilised.

[image]

Within the default.xhtml template, I have defined the `<h:head>` tags although it appears to still not be working. Is there anything I am missing which is not allowing this to be loaded?

If you require more information, please let me know. I would like to resolve this issue as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue here.

By default, I believe that JSF resource handling mechanism does not support for mapping the `resource` directory which resides in the WEB-INF directory. In order to overwrite this default, you need to explicitly define a new `<context-param>` within the project web.xml file.

The following fragment of code below specifies the directory used for resource lookup in the file system of the web application.

`<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
</context-param>`

Comment: Noted should be that this is JSF 2.2 specific. For older JSF versions, you'd still need to move the folder back to its documented place (and if necessary add a security constraint to prevent direct access; this is answered several times before).

Comment: @BalusC, appreciate the clarification. On a side note, do you have any of your personal recommended sources for learning the in's and out's of the JSF framework?

Comment: Start at https://jsf.zeef.com. By the way, I hope that you're very well aware that your XHTML templates are this way publicly accessible, which violates the recommendation in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not You'd better move them outside the `/WEB-INF/resources` folder. Or, better, stick to JSF's own recommendation of `/resources` location for public webapp resources.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the link, much appreciated. In regards to your comment regarding security concern, I am well aware of this and I have read your answer in the post you have provided. I have declared this security constraint in my `web.xml`, so I believe that everything is good now.