# How to send message or redirect user when security constraint block access

Tags: jsf, glassfish, web.xml, http-status-code-403, security-constraint

I have following security constraint in my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>

        <web-resource-name>Protected Admin Area</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/administrator/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/faces/backend/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

It`s works fine. But i would like to redirect users (already logged user with some assign role but not role administrator). In this case. When user trying to access to url http://mywebap//administrator/* he get a response from server

```
403 Forbiden.
```

I would here not display this but redirect user to some more friendly view. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply configure the desired page as a custom HTTP 403 error page in `web.xml`.

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/403.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

This assumes that you've covered `*.xhtml` as [URL pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why) of `FacesServlet`. And, it's being placed in `/WEB-INF` to [prevent direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not).