# Could not resolve NavigationCase for outcome: /dashboard-banking.xhtml

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, subdirectory

So, I have several .xhtml files in Web Pages folder (in Netbeans, it is WebContent in Eclipse). I can access them without problem. But I created folder named "private" and put some .xhtml files in it

Structure:

```
Web Pages
  |__ private
     |__ dashboard.xhtml
  |__ index.xhtml
  |__ error.xhtml
```

I can't access:

```
localhost:8080/Project/private/dashboard.xhtml
```

It throws an exception:

```
Could not resolve NavigationCase for outcome: /dashboard-banking.xhtml
```

I'm using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.3 and Tomcat 7.0.68

Comment: Are there any servlet filters or security constrinats mapped to `/private/*`? At least, your problem is based on the information provided so far not reproducible for me and anyone else in the world having a scratchpad project with everything set to defaults and using latest versions of sane software products. Try doing the same yourself and revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank BalusC on answer - I don't have any constraints defined for that path (nor any other). I edited my question and added response I get from browser. So you think /private/* url pattern should work? You're suggesting me to create new project and see what happens? I created this project yesterday with latest versions of software but no help

Comment: Wow, when you said "I can't access", we all understood you literally cannot access the page, but as per your edit you actually can access the page. It just threw an exception while producing the HTML output. If you had used a minimalistic test page without JSF components and such it would have worked flawlessly. The exception in turn is pretty self-explaining. Have you tried to literally interpret it in the context of the new URL?

Comment: Look, I don't bother you because I'm lazy but because I'm struggling for 3 hours with navigation. Probably I don't have enough knowledge on JSF, so don't be mad. Thank you very much on your response, this is probably problem connected with called referencing template that is inside WEB-INF and my path is not good. Can you suggest me how to reference file from folder to WEB-INF file? "../WEB-INF/template.xhtml or /WEB-INF/.. isn't correct as I see

Comment: Huh? If I was bothered I would have ignored the question in its entirety instead of trying to help you to help us and yourself. As to `/WEB-INF` story, no clue how that's related to the problem as this is nowhere visible in the information provided so far, but this should provide insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not It would at least explain a lot if you actually used `/WEB-INF` instead of `/private` and incorrectly overgeneralized it in the question without testifying the question as if you were trying to answer it.

Comment: I found it - one of the included xhtml files had outcome that wasn't correct after I transferred dashboard.xhtml to folder. After editing it, it works. @BalusC, you can smile now, kisses :))