# Include meta to JSF

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a JSF page which include `<head>...</head>` from another page. Basically it's looks like this:

```
<ui:include src="/path/head.xhtml"/>
<h:body>
...
</h:body>
```

I want to add unique `<meta name="description" content="Unique content">` to each page which use  `<ui:include src="/path/head.xhtml"/>`.
I have 2 ideas:

1. Can I put `<meta name="description".../>` to head-page and overwrite it on include-pages?
2. Or maybe I can put somehow this `<meta.../>` from include pages to head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several ways:

1. Use `<ui:insert>` without `name` and have body of `<ui:include>` override it:

   `/WEB-INF/includes/head.xhtml`

   ```
   <h:head>
       ...
       <ui:insert>
           <meta name="description" content="Default description" />
       </ui:insert>
       ...
   </h:head>
   ```

   `/page.xhtml`

   ```
   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/head.xhtml">
       <meta name="description" content="Overridden description" />
   </ui:include>
   ```
2. Use `<ui:insert>` with `name`, and use `<ui:decorate><ui:define>` instead of `<ui:include>`:

   `/WEB-INF/includes/head.xhtml`

   ```
   <h:head>
       ...
       <ui:insert name="description">
           <meta name="description" content="Default description" />
       </ui:insert>
       ...
   </h:head>
   ```

   `/page.xhtml`

   ```
   <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/includes/head.xhtml">
       <ui:define name="description">
           <meta name="description" content="Overridden description" />
       </ui:define>
   </ui:decorate>
   ```
3. Simply use `<ui:param>` with solely the meta content to keep code DRY when you already have a default description:

   `/WEB-INF/includes/head.xhtml`

   ```
   <h:head>
       ...
       <meta name="description" content="#{empty description ? 'Default description' : description}" />
       ...
   </h:head>
   ```

   `/page.xhtml`

   ```
   <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/head.xhtml">
       <ui:param name="description" value="Overridden description" />
   </ui:include>
   ```

#### See also:

- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/)
- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)